# What to Download?

Tags: drivers

So I just built my second computer onto which I put Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. My main rig runs Windows 10 and I had to install a bunch of USB drivers, audio drivers, chipset stuff, etc. Is any of that necessary for an Ubuntu build? The MSI website (mobo manufacturer) does not have drivers for Linux. Thanks guys!

Comment: Hopefully everything will just work. The installation comes with a bunch of firmware for various devices. Your question is too broad! Please try to use your system, and ask a question when you run into a problem, then we will help you find and install the driver or whatever else needs to be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try booting off of an Ubuntu live dvd/usb to see if your devices work out of the box. There's a good chance everything will work just fine and you won't have to install any drivers. If something doesn't work, post here and we will be happy to help.